# Write mysql queries with bit wise operators in mybatis mapper xml

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mybatis, ibatis

How do we write sql queries which has bit wise operators in mybatis mapper xml.
I have a query which has bitwise operator AND (&) in the where clause.

```
WHERE id=1000 AND NOT status&4 AND NOT status&16 ; //This is the where clause of the query.
```

id and status are columns of the table. status column is INT data type. When i write this query in mybatis mapper file it shows an error for the & operator? and when application runs throws an exception

```
org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance
```

Comment: Does it work when you simplify the `WHERE` clause?  *(Remove the bitwise operators...  If it runs fine without that part, then you've shown that part is introducing the symptoms...)*

Answer (score 1):

Since you're writing the query in an XML file, you should escape the ampersand character using `&amp;`.

Your queries should look like this

```
WHERE id=1000 AND NOT status&amp;4 AND NOT status&amp;16
```